# Check if a setting is set

Tags: android

I need for my APP the right time. So, I was thinking to check if it is not set the Automatic time, forcing to the user to set it. Is there any way to check that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to force the user to use the network time on their devices. Even if you do manage that, the network time itself could be incorrect.

A better solution would be to get the time from your server and adjust it for the user's time zone.